# Re-using the values with in terraform.tfvars

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I have variables defined with the values as below in terraform.tfvars

```
oke_vcn_cidr               = "10.0.0.0/21"
```

I would like to add the same value of oke_vcn_cidr variable in my egress rules in the same terraform.tfvars instead of hardcoding again.

Currently, I have given the destination with the same value as below.

```
egress_security_rules_intlb = {
  sl1 = { protocol = "6", destination = "10.0.0.0/21", stateless = "false", min = 10256, max = 10256, description = "outbound traffic to public load balancer" }
}
```

How do I fetch the value of this variable  **oke_vcn_cidr**  and replace it with destination value within terraform.tfvars

```
egress_security_rules_intlb = {
  sl1 = { protocol = "6", destination = **<value of variable oke_vcn_cidr>**, stateless = "false", min = 10256, max = 10256, description = "outbound traffic to public load balancer" }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this solution, we cannot implement as per my usecase... I have this value in multiple places in tfvars and I have to use the same in multiple modules...  I am trying to overcome writing the same value multiple times in the same file...

Answer (score 3):

Sadly you **can't do this**. Variables can't reference other variables. Instead you would have to create a local variable:

```
locals {
   egress_security_rules_intlb = {for k, v in var.egress_security_rules_intlb:
                   k => merge(v, {destination = var.oke_vcn_cidr})}
}
```

Then you have to use `local.egress_security_rules_intlb` in the rest
of your module.